# SQL Deadlocks Insert Update statments in Stored Procedure

Tags: database-deadlocks

I have a very basic table called Titles as below,

```
TitleID - auto identity and PK
UserID - reference key to User table
Title - varchar
IsPrimary - bit
```

Only one index which is PK Clustered Index on TitleID

Now I'm inserting records in this table via stored procedure in a ReadCommitted transaction,

This stored procedure inserts the record in a table with IsPrimary = 1 and update all other titles to 0

```
INSERT INTO Titles(...)
    VALUES (...)

UPDATE T
SET IsPrimary = 0
FROM    Titles T
WHERE T.UserID = @UserID AND T.JobTitle != @Title
```

The moment I test this in multi user scenario I hit deadlock issues. If I remove the UPDATE command from stored proc then everything works perfectly fine...

I tried to create non clustered indexes on the lookup column and also tried WITH (ROWLOCK) hint in update statement but nothing seems to work.

When I ran sql statements and viewed the estimated execution plan I can see both update the clustered index and I'm thinking this is where it fails during multiple user scenario...

I believe it's fairly simple scenario and lots of people should have implemented this kind of behaviour in high transaction system but I can't finding anything on how to approach/solve this issue and your help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your deadlock is probably on the index resource.

In the execution plan look for bookmark/key lookups and create a non-clustered index covering those fields - that way the 'read' of the data for the UPDATE will not clash with the 'write' of the INSERT.

Comment: Kev thank for reply. I also think deadlock is on the index resource only but for actual update statement not for filter/lookup...because it's cluster index when ever anything changes in the table it needs to be updated (hope my understanding is correct) and at the same time another insert might be happening which will trigger deadlock. Do you see what I mean? If I understood correctly you regarding creating non cluster index, as I mentioned in the initial post, I created non index cluster on columns used in where clause of update statement but it made no difference..any other suggestion?

Comment: No the inserts (no matter how many concurrent) shouldn't give a deadlock - at the worst you get blocking, but not deadlocking.  You really need to examine the output of the deadlock graph to find out the exact resources being locked - it's difficult from here :)